# "Player2" is unable to do the same things as "player"

Tags: python, pygame, game-development, mu

```
import random

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 500

background = Actor('background')
player = Actor('player')
enemy = Actor('enemy')
money = Actor('money', pos=(300, 300))
player2 = Actor('alien')
score = 0
score2 = 0
player.x = 200
player.y = 200


def draw():
    screen.clear()
    background.draw()
    player.draw()
    enemy.draw()
    money.draw()
    player2.draw()


def update():
    global score
    if keyboard.right:
        player.x = player.x + 4
    if keyboard.left:
        player.x = player.x - 4
    if keyboard.down:
        player.y = player.y + 4
    if keyboard.up:
        player.y = player.y - 4

    if player.x > WIDTH:
        player.x = WIDTH
    if player.x < 0:
        player.x = 0
    if player.y < 0:
        player.y = 0
    if player.y > HEIGHT:
        player.y = HEIGHT

    if enemy.x < player.x:
        enemy.x = enemy.x + 1
    if enemy.x > player.x:
        enemy.x = enemy.x - 1
    if enemy.y < player.y:
        enemy.y = enemy.y + 1
    if enemy.y > player.y:
        enemy.y = enemy.y - 1
    if player.colliderect(enemy):
        exit()

    if money.colliderect(player):
        money.x = random.randint(0, WIDTH)
        money.y = random.randint(0, HEIGHT)
        score = score + 1
        print ('Score:', score)

    if keyboard.d:
        player2.x = player2.x + 4
    if keyboard.a:
        player2.x = player2.x - 4
    if keyboard.s:
        player2.y = player2.y + 4
    if keyboard.w:
        player2.y = player2.y - 4
    if player.colliderect(player2):
        exit()

    if player2.x > WIDTH:
        player2.x = WIDTH
    if player2.x < 0:
        player2.x = 0
    if player2.y < 0:
        player2.y = 0
    if player2.y > HEIGHT:
        player2.y = HEIGHT
```

I just tried to introduce a player2 to into my python game that I am making in MU-editor, I can see player2 and move him, but there are some problems. enemy is not chasing player2 and player2 can not pick up money. I also want to add a score2 variable for player2 and store the score when he collides with the money.

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question, try labeling what file we are looking at and what you have tried so far.

Comment: It is a python file and I am using MU editor. I am making a game with two players and an enemy. I want the enemy to be able to chase player2, instead of only chasing player. I also want to add the score and score2 together as a total sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pickup the money, you have to add the collision test between `playyer2` and `money`:

```py
score2 = 0

def update():
    global score, score2

    # [...]

    if money.colliderect(player2):
        money.x = random.randint(0, WIDTH)
        money.y = random.randint(0, HEIGHT)
        score2 += 1
```

For chasing `player` or `player2` you have to find the player which is nearer to the enemy. Compare the square of the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) from the enemy to the players and chase the player which is nearer:

```py
def update():

    dx1, dy1 = player.x - enemy.x, player.y - enemy.y
    dx2, dy2 = player2.x - enemy.x, player2.y - enemy.y
    dist1sq = dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1
    dist2sq = dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2 

    player_near = player if dist1sq < dist2sq else player2

    if enemy.x < player_near.x:
        enemy.x += 1
    if enemy.x > player_near.x:
        enemy.x -= 1
    if enemy.y < player_near.y:
        enemy.y += 1
    if enemy.y > player_near.y:
        enemy.y -= 1
    if player.colliderect(enemy):
        exit()
    if player2.colliderect(enemy):
        exit()

    # [...]
```

function `update`:

```py
def update():
    global score, score2

    if keyboard.right:
        player.x += 4
    if keyboard.left:
        player.x -= 4
    if keyboard.down:
        player.y += 4
    if keyboard.up:
        player.y -= 4

    if player.x > WIDTH:
        player.x = WIDTH
    if player.x < 0:
        player.x = 0
    if player.y < 0:
        player.y = 0
    if player.y > HEIGHT:
        player.y = HEIGHT

    if keyboard.d:
        player2.x += 4
    if keyboard.a:
        player2.x -= 4
    if keyboard.s:
        player2.y += 4
    if keyboard.w:
        player2.y -= 4

    if player2.x > WIDTH:
        player2.x = WIDTH
    if player2.x < 0:
        player2.x = 0
    if player2.y < 0:
        player2.y = 0
    if player2.y > HEIGHT:
        player2.y = HEIGHT

    dx1, dy1 = player.x - enemy.x, player.y - enemy.y
    dx2, dy2 = player2.x - enemy.x, player2.y - enemy.y
    dist1sq = dx1*dx1 + dy1*dy1
    dist2sq = dx2*dx2 + dy2*dy2 

    player_near = player if dist1sq < dist2sq else player2

    if enemy.x < player_near.x:
        enemy.x += 1
    if enemy.x > player_near.x:
        enemy.x -= 1
    if enemy.y < player_near.y:
        enemy.y += 1
    if enemy.y > player_near.y:
        enemy.y -= 1
    if player.colliderect(enemy):
        exit()
    if player2.colliderect(enemy):
        exit()

    if money.colliderect(player):
        money.x = random.randint(0, WIDTH)
        money.y = random.randint(0, HEIGHT)
        score = score + 1

    if money.colliderect(player2):
        money.x = random.randint(0, WIDTH)
        money.y = random.randint(0, HEIGHT)
        score2 += 1
```

Comment: I removed if player.colliderect(player2): and found out that enemy and player2 are colliding instantly. How can I make it so they start in different locations? I updated the code in the post now btw.

Comment: @jacobstarheim Do not change the code in the question! If you change the code, then my answer becomes useless. I don't know why `enemy` and `player2` have the same location. You set `player.x = 200` `player.y = 200`. You've to do something else for `player2`